# Disable Querying LAN Address when on Mobile

Tags: networking, vpn

We have a local server with a domain name and DNS, all *only* accessible on a LAN or via VPN. We use this to maintain a few services synced up.

Is there a way to disable phones from trying to access those addresses when not connected to the local SSID or VPN? They wouldn't be able to connect anyways, and it would help to avoid it constantly trying to resolve the address.

We've considered a *hosts* file approach, but that would just block those addresses entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The mobiles can only connect to Wi-Fi (unless plugged in somehow).  If this DNS is not visible on Wi-Fi, there isnt a problem.

If it is, then you can use a different subnet for this DNS.  For example

- Wifi on `192.168.2.x`
- Local on `192.168.1.x`